# Closest number to average in array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a program that user will put numbers and I need to get the closest number to average.

```
//average
        for (i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
            total = total + arr[i];
        }

        double average = total/arr.length;

        System.out.println("Average is: " + average);
```

Then I'm trying to do this;

```
//more close to average

        for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

            if (arr[i] > average) {
                System.out.println("Numbers above average: " + arr[i]);
            } else if (arr[i] < average) {
                System.out.println("Numbers below average; " + arr[i]);
            }else
                System.out.println("Wrong!");
        }
```

My problem is, when if I enter numbers 1 12 17 23 62, average is correct: 23.0
But output is like this:

```
Numbers below average; 1
Numbers below average; 12
Numbers below average; 17
Numbers below average; 23
Numbers below average; 62
```

Why after number 62 doesn't pass to else if statement?

Many thanks

**All Code**

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;
        double total = 0;

        System.out.println("Indicate number of values: ");
        int [] arr = new int[scanner.nextInt()];

        System.out.println("Indicate numbers: ");
        for (i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
                int num = scanner.nextInt();
                arr[i] = num;
        }

        //average
        for (i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
            total = total + arr[i];
        }

        double average = total/arr.length;

        System.out.println("Average is: " + average);

        total = 0;


        //derivation
        for (i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
            total += Math.pow((arr[i] - average), 2);
        }

        average = total/(arr.length-1);
        double deviation = Math.sqrt(average);

        //variance
        double variance = Math.pow((deviation),2);
        System.out.println("Variance is: "+ variance);


        //more close to average

        for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

            if (arr[i] > average) {
                System.out.println("Numbers above average: " + arr[i]);
            } else if (arr[i] < average) {
                System.out.println("Numbers below average; " + arr[i]);
            }else
                System.out.println("Wrong!");
        }





    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are recalculating the `total` and `average` values again , print that value and you will see that is greater than 62:

You need to change your code to the following:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Indicate number of values: ");
        int [] arr = new int[scanner.nextInt()];

        System.out.println("Indicate numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
                arr[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

         //average
        double total = 0;
        for (int i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
            total = total + arr[i];
        }

        double average = total/arr.length;

        System.out.println("Average is: " + average);

        total = 0;
 
       //derivation
        for (int i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
            total += Math.pow((arr[i] - average), 2);
        }
        double deviation = Math.sqrt(total/(arr.length-1));

        //variance
        double variance = Math.pow((deviation),2);
        System.out.println("Variance is: "+ variance);


        //more close to average
        for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > average) {
                System.out.println("Numbers above average: " + arr[i]);
            } else if (arr[i] < average) {
                System.out.println("Numbers below average; " + arr[i]);
            }else
                System.out.println("Wrong!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        int[] arr =  {1, 12, 17, 23, 62};
        Vector<Integer> BelowAvg = new Vector<Integer>();
        Vector<Integer> AboveAvg = new Vector<Integer>();
        Vector<Integer> Avg = new Vector<Integer>();
        int total = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            total += + arr[i];
        }

        double average = total/arr.length;

        System.out.println("Average is: " + average);
        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > average) {
                AboveAvg.add(arr[i]);
            } else if (arr[i] < average) {
                BelowAvg.add(arr[i]);
            } else
                Avg.add(arr[i]);
        }
        
        System.out.print("Numbers above average: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < AboveAvg.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(AboveAvg.get(i) + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println(AboveAvg.get(AboveAvg.size() - 1));
        
        System.out.print("Numbers below average: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < BelowAvg.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(BelowAvg.get(i) + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println(BelowAvg.get(BelowAvg.size() - 1));
        
        System.out.print("Numbers equal to average: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < Avg.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(Avg.get(i) + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println(Avg.get(Avg.size() - 1));
    }
}
```

I did this, that I think it does what you want.